# User being logged out of drupal when using form redirect

Tags: 7, forms, commerce, users

Looking at my logs I have an issue. I have not been able to recreate it myself.

I have a form which an anonymous user fills out. This form takes an email address. When submitting the form I take that email address and either log the user in or create an account and log the user in.

This code is working fine. As I have several `watchdog()` calls going in as the user who has been logged in.

The code then creates an order in Drupal commerce (with the user account above). I have a valid orderid created with the above user.

I then have:

```
watchdog('MyMod', t("Logged in as user));
drupal_goto('checkout/' . $orderid . '/review');
```

The `watchdog()` goes in as the user. When I hit `checkout/????/review` I then get an **access denied** for an Anonymous user.

This is only happening some of the time. As I said I have not been able to reproduce. What could be causing the `drupal_goto()` to log my user out.

**Update**

I now use

```
watchdog('MyMod', t("Insert in ref table complete"));
$formstate['redirect'] = 'checkout/' . $orderid . '/review';
```

To redirect my user however I am still getting the same issue.

**Update 2**

With some code.

Log out user

```
function _mymod_logout_user() {
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid > 1) {
    module_invoke_all('user_logout', $user);
    session_destroy();
  }
}
```

Create User

```
function _mymod_create_user($mail) {
  global $user;
  _mymod_logout_user();
  if ($user->uid != 0) {
    return $user;
  }

  $account = user_load_by_mail($mail);

  if ($account == FALSE) {


    $password = 'random12!££SsjsjaJAAJA3'; //made up

    //set up the user fields
    $fields = array(
      'name' => $mail,
      'mail' => $mail,
      'pass' => $password,
      'status' => 1,
      'init' => 'email address',
      'roles' => array(
        DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID => 'authenticated user',
      ),
    );

    $account = user_save('', $fields);
  }

  // If the user is 1 then we want to return false as they will be logged in as admin
  if ($account->uid == 1) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  $form_state = array();
  $form_state['uid'] = $account->uid;
  user_login_submit(array(), $form_state);

  return $account;
}
```

Create Order

```
function _mymod_create_order($sku, $mail) {
  global $user;
  $user = _mymod_create_user($mail);

  // User is trying to create an account under user 1 so return nothing.
  // can only do this if logged in a user 1 not anon
  if ($user == FALSE) {
    return;
  }
  $uid = $user->uid;

  $order = commerce_order_new($uid, 'checkout_review');
  $product = commerce_product_load_by_sku($sku);
  $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, 1, $order->order_id, array());
  commerce_line_item_save($line_item);

  $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items[] = $line_item;
  commerce_order_save($order);
  return $order->order_id;
}
```

Insert into custom table

```
function _mymod_insert_ref_table($orderid, $ref) {
  db_insert('mymod_reference_table')
    ->fields(array(
      'orderid' => $orderid,
      'ref' => $ref,
    ))
    ->execute();
}
```

Form submit function

```
function mymod_form_submit($form, &$formstate) {
  global $conf;

  $sku = //Code that generates a SKU;

  $orderid = _mymod_create_order($sku, $form['email']['#value']); //email has all ready been validated by drupal

  $ref = // Call to WS that returns a reference number
  _mymod_insert_ref_table($orderid, $ref);
  watchdog('My Mod', t("Insert in ref table complete")); // This watchdog message goes in as the logged in user!
  $formstate['redirect'] = 'checkout/' . $orderid . '/review';  // When I reach this page I am logged out sometimes...

}
```

Comment: Logging in a user simply based on an e-mail address sounds dicey - how are you preventing illegitimate account access?

Comment: Personal information is not stored. Order history is not visible. After the order has been created passed via web services to a third party system. Can then view status of order from there.

Answer (score 2):

You should better use `$form['redirect']` within a form rather than `drupal_goto()`.

> If you use drupal_goto() you will short cut the form processing skipping any other form_submission functions that have attached themselves to the form. Thus, if you use path_auto and do a drupal_goto while processing a node form, a nice path will not be added to your node because the drupal_goto() was executed before pathauto's node submission handler was called.

[Source](https://drupal.org/comment/1135780#comment-1135780)

This was before the original post was edited. Regarding the logout issue, let us review your procedure.

So essentially: when a form is submitted, `mymod_form_submit()` calls `_mymod_create_order()`, which calls `_mymod_create_user()`, which in turn calls `_mymod_logout_user()`. All of them unconditionally so far.

If not user 1, you will logout the user and then back in `_mymod_create_user()` you will attempt to create if necessary and then log the user in.

When you attempt to login the user via `user_login_submit()`, Drupal will call [`drupal_session_regenerate()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/function/drupal_session_regenerate/7). There, in an attempt to prevent several nasty security possibilities such as session fixation, will generate a new session ID. I suspect the trouble is somewhere there, depending on what exactly happens in the code that displays the redirection page "checkout/...".

In order to deal with this issue I would recommend you to adopt the procedure that other modules use to deal with the possibility that an anonymous user needs to login / be created. Ubercart and Drupal Commerce certainly deal with that. Personally I would suggest to take a look at Ubercart file "uc_cart/uc_cart.pages.inc", function `uc_cart_checkout()`

Comment: (Assuming that `drupal_goto()` is happening indeed in the form processing, no code provided.

Comment: The code is being executed in the form submit function.

Comment: I have changed my code. Will monitor the logs and will see what happens.

Comment: sadly this did solve the issue. It appeared again today.

Comment: You mean it did not? The principle is correct though. Please post some code.

Comment: Correct. Did not. Hopefully my code is better than replying to comments. Will flesh out the question.

Comment: Ok, again it is not clear to me: at exactly which point of form processing is `_mymod_logout_user()` called? I believe that my answer to your original question is adequate. The form API indeed redirects, I believe something with your session handling goes wrong.

Comment: _mymod_logout_user()  is called at the start (unless user 1). Then it will log you in again or create a new account and log you in.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen issues with user appearing to get logged out when the site can be accessed both through http://www.domain.com and http://domain.com: The drupal_goto() call could send them from one version to the other, thus voiding the session cookie.  Have you tried using .htaccess to redirect the www.domain.com to domain.com, or the other way around?

Comment: We have the base_url set in the config file as https://subdomain.domain.com. We have a rewrite rule to redirect http traffic to https. This is one outside of apache.

Comment: Just make sure that apache doesn't also allow www.subdomain.domain.com. There are instructions in .htaccess to avoid that

Comment: http-->https rewrite could break sessions, too...

Answer (score 0):

Check out if protocol changes. If you are being sent http to https, the http session won't continue into https.

Comment: Amazing. You just solved my problem! Could you re post your answer in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/104282/user-register-and-login-functions-are-called-from-hook-form-alter-but-user-isn so I can give you some bounty?

Comment: We all help one ahother here for free.

Comment: I'd already had bountied it anyway. Seems only fair to give it to the person who helped me solve it.

Comment: Then by all means :)