# User register and login functions are called from hook_form_alter, but user isn't logged in

Tags: 7, users, forms

**Background**

I'm attaching the user register form, to the node create form with `hook_form_alter`. that way I create a node and user at once.

In order to validate and register the user, in `hook_form_alter` I add the relevant functions to my node form submit and validation calls.

```
function mymodule_form_alter form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   ....

    $form['#validate'][] = 'user_account_form_validate';
    $form['#submit'][] = 'user_register_submit';
```

**Problem**

The node is created and the user is created but the user isn't logged in.

- Why isn't the user logged in?

The user register and login code seems to be running ok (see below), I can only think somehow the node creation is logging the user out? I have no idea how to continue debugging this.

**Debugging**

Thanks to Felix, I was able to debug by logging dpm (because it doesn't appear on the page) and the code is running correctly.

`user_login_submit` is called from `user_register_submit`

```
function user_login_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  $user = user_load($form_state['uid']);
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'user/' . $user->uid;
  user_login_finalize($form_state);
}
```

And then `user_login_finalize` is called.

```
function user_login_finalize(&$edit = array()) {
  global $user;
  watchdog('user', 'Session opened for %name.', array('%name' => $user->name));
  // Update the user table timestamp noting user has logged in.
  // This is also used to invalidate one-time login links.
  $user->login = REQUEST_TIME;
  db_update('users')
    ->fields(array('login' => $user->login))
    ->condition('uid', $user->uid)
    ->execute();

  // Regenerate the session ID to prevent against session fixation attacks.
  // This is called before hook_user in case one of those functions fails
  // or incorrectly does a redirect which would leave the old session in place.
  drupal_session_regenerate();

  user_module_invoke('login', $edit, $user);
}
```

I printed out `$edit` and `$user` and `$edit` is `$form_state` and `$user` is the newly created user. I can't see anything going wrong. The session opening is logged by watchdog, however perhaps it's never assigned?

How else could I continue to debug this? Could `drupal_session_regenerate()` be logging me out?

EDIT: I switched the `user_register_submit` to `logintoboggan_user_register_submit`, which worked on my dev environment but then broke on production with the same problem as above.

It doesn't appear to be a code problem, but something to do with the database or a setting. I dropped my production front end in front of my dev backend and it works fine, so it's some sort of database setting (which could of course effect the front end code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the minute I put up a bounty I spot the answer. The problem was the switch between HTTPS and HTTP was killing my session. I'd accidentally secured the URL Alias not the actual URL.

Spotted it from another bountied question answer by @Alexei Reyu so waiting to see if he'll come and put his answer up here.

Comment: something else you can do so that your session won't die between the protocal switch is to set `$conf['https']=TRUE;` in your settings file. See https://drupal.org/https-information

*If you want to support mixed-mode HTTPS and HTTP sessions open up sites/default/settings.php and add $conf['https'] = TRUE;. This enables you use the same session over HTTP and HTTPS both*

Answer (score 2):

If a redirect is happening after print('x') then it will be lost. dmp() should show up however I prefer using [Devel Debug Log](https://drupal.org/project/devel_debug_log) in these instances so you know if then code is running then it will output to the log.

You can use the function ddl('log message') or ddl($array) and then check the report of what has been output once your code has run.

I realise this isn't actually answering your question but may make debugging easier...

Comment: Hmm that's really interesting. It could be perhaps they're lost somehow. Cheers, I'll go give this a shot now!

Comment: Cheers, that debugging was super useful. Turns out the code is running, and for some reason the login doesn't work. Not sure why because the correct functions are running. But that was super useful in getting this far.

Comment: Well Alexei didn't turn up, so have some bounty. Thanks for the super useful debugging tip!

Answer (score 0):

```
       1.  https://drupal.org/node/1545970
       2.  http://drupal.org/node/910598
```

It is may be problem of https and http . check session variables is present or not.Please check this both ulr. it is may be help to your output